# What verb do you use to describe the action of making your hand into a fist?

Tags: word-choice

What verb do you use to describe the action of making your hand into a fist? Can I use the verb *curl*? For example:

> He **curled** his hand into a fist.

Answer (score -1):

"Curled" works, as you can see at :[Google books "curled his hand into a fist"](https://tinyurl.com/tttky4e)

Another possibility is "balled his fist": 
[Google books "balled his fist"](https://tinyurl.com/sz4ztja)

You can also say "balled her hand into a fist".
There is also "clenched his fist".

Comment: The normal word is clench.